# CGAffineTransformMakeTranslation except one subview

Tags: ios, objective-c

Is it possible to apply CGAffineTransformMakeTranslation to a view except one of its subview ?

Answer (score 1):

You can translate the superview and then translate in opposite direction the subview you need not to be moved